# Get element in list with lowest count of *

Tags: python, list, lambda, count, min

I have a list and I want to find the element that has the lowest count of '*'.

```
mylist = ['12*3','12345**6','11234']
```

So the answer in this little test is '11234'

This works but is slow (I'm working with massive genomic data:

```
sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: x.count('*'))[0]
```

This is less eloquent but works:

```
values = map(lambda x: x.count('*'), mylist)
print mylist[values.index(min(values))]
```

Is there a better way?
I was trying to do a schwartzian transformation but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with `key` parameter:

```
>>> mylist = ['12*3','12345**6','11234']
>>> min(mylist, key=lambda x: x.count('*'))
'11234'
```

`key` is a function that is called on each item on the iterable to specify the ordering the same way as in `sorted`.

Above approach will result to **O(n)** time complexity where as sorting is **O(n log n)**.

**Update:** If your strings are really long then you could count the occurrences of `*` in a loop and reject the string as soon as count is the same as current minimum. You could also terminate the search if string with 0 occurrences is found:

```
def find(l):
    min_item = None
    min_val = float('inf')

    for x in l:
        current = 0
        for c in x:
            current += (c == '*')
            if current >= min_val:
                break
        else:
            # Found new minimum, update
            min_item = x
            min_val = current

        # Can't get lower than 0
        if min_val == 0:
            break

    return min_item

print(find(['12*3','11234', '12345**6', '1'])) # '11234'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may further improve the performance by creating the separate function for `key` instead of `lambda` as *lambda functions* are slow. For example as:

```
def get_asterisk_count(my_string):
    return my_string.count('*')

mylist = ['12*3','12345**6','11234']
min(mylist, key=get_asterisk_count)
```

Below are the `timeit` stats:

- Using `lambda` function: 1.25 usec

  ```
  mquadri$ python -m "timeit" -s "mylist = ['12*3','12345**6','11234']" "min(mylist, key=lambda x: x.count('*'))"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 usec per loop
  ```
- Using separate function: 1.19 usec

  ```
  mquadri$ python -m "timeit" -s "mylist = ['12*3','12345**6','11234']" "def get_asterisk_count(my_string): return my_string.count('*')" "min(mylist, key=get_asterisk_count)"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 usec per loop
  ```

Comment: I think the differences in your timings are not appreciable. Certainly not enough to support the claim that "lambda functions are slow", or--more generously--_slower_. When I run the same snippets multiple times, sometimes the named function comes out ahead, sometimes the `lambda` comes out ahead. This leads me to believe the differences are purely noise and/or some confounding factor. AFAIK, in CPython, there is no real difference in the implementation of `lambda` and `def` functions. I don't see any reason why the execution of a `lambda` would be slower than the equivalent named function.